# Is there a simple way to use library blocks to update/edit workspace parameters in Simulink?

Tags: simulink, simulink-library

I have a few hundred functions in a model which all output a parameter, not all at the same time. Each time one of these functions completes its calculation, I want to pick up this parameter, and update a vector in the workspace which has to be human readable, so I am only interested in the most recent ten or so values.

I would like to use a library (triggered?) function to collate these values (this seems okay) and send them to the workspace vector (this doesn't). How do I send update one vector in the workspace using a library function that is called at multiple instances in the model?